# Can I test a function mapping data into a child component using Jest and Enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am making an API call which returns an array of objects.  I am then mapping these objects onto a child component.  My idea for how to test this would be to mock the API call using Jest and test to see if the number of child components rendered is equal to the number of objects.  I'm not actually sure I need to mock the API call and think it may be simpler to just declare an array and use that.

Here is an example of the array I would be using for my API call return.

```
let organizationRoles = [
    {name : "2nd Project Manager", assigned : false}, 
    {name : "Executive Sponser", assigned: false}, 
    {name : "CFO or Finance Contact", assigned: false},
    {name : "OI&T Contact", assigned: false},
    {name : "Payroll Contact", assigned: false},
    {name : "HR Contact", assigned: false}
]
```

and here is the test I am trying to run.

```
it('renders the appropriate number of cards', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<AssignRoles />);
    const cardHolder = wrapper.find('#assign-roles-roles-page');
    expect(cardHolder.children()).toHaveLength(organizationRoles.length)
})
```

My main issue is I haven't figured out where to inject the array.

Here is the code I want to test from my `AssignRoles` component.

```
<div className={styles.rolesPage} id="assign-roles-roles-page">
   {organizationRoles.map((roles, key)=> {
       return(<AssignRolesCard name={roles.name} assignee={roles.assignee} id={key} handleFormOpen={handleFormOpen}/>)
   })}
</div>
```

As requested here is my API call:

```
axios
      .get(URL, config)
      .then(response => {
        const organizationRoles = response.data;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        if (error.response.status === 401 && token) {
          this.renewToken();
        }
      });
```

I am still fairly new to Jest testing and want to understand how to better use mocks in my testing.

Comment: Can you show the implementation where the component fetches the data?

Comment: @Teneff Do you mean the API call to get organizationRoles?  I have updated my question to include this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It mainly depends on the implementation that you want to test. So if your component is responsible to fetch the data from the API you should mock the function being used within the component

for example

```
import axios from 'axios';

jest.mock('axios');

describe('given a component that is fetching data using fetch', () => {

  describe('if the api retuns someData', () => {
    let wrapper;
    beforeAll(() => {
      axios.get.mockResolvedValue(someData);
      wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent />);
    });
    it('should render X', () => {
      expect(wrapper). // assert something 
    });
  });

  describe('if the api returns some other data, () => {
    let wrapper;
    beforeAll(() => {
      axios.get.mockResolvedValue(someOtherData);
      wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent />);
    });
    it('should render Y', () => {
      expect(wrapper). // assert something 
    });
  });
});
```

if your component receives the data as a property you should provide the data as property within the test:

```
describe('given a component that receives data as prop', () => {
  describe('with some other data, () => {
    let wrapper;
    beforeAll(() => {
      wrapper = shallow(<MyOtherComponent data={someOtherData} />);
    });
    it('should render X', () => {
      expect(wrapper). // assert something 
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Part of my issue though is rendering the <MyOtherComponent /> as a mapped function.  In my code above I am mapping the API data into the component.  So there really should be multiple instances of <MyOtherComponent />.  I am not sure how test is this mapping is occuring correctly

Comment: You can test that if the `axios.get` returns an array with 6 objects your component should render 6 `AssignRolesCard`, or you could use `expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot()` which will save snapshot of what's being rendered by your component and if the implementation changes it will be reflected in the snapshot as well